# Terminate current thread

Tags: c++11, stdthread

How can I cleanly terminate the current child std::thread in C++11? The decision to terminate is made at a function call depth of 4 or 5 from the main thread method so I don't want to check whether I should terminate at each return. I have looked at exit and terminate but it looks like they terminate the entire process and not just the current thread.

For instance:

```
void A() { B(); ... }
void B() { C(); ... }
void C() { D(); ... }
void D() { /* oops! need to terminate this thread*/ }

void main() {
  thread t(A);
}
```

Comment: Just return from the threads main function.

Comment: Ah, then no it's not possible to use standard C++ functionality to exit the thread. If the compiler also supports [C11 threads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread) you could use e.g. [`thrd_exit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_exit), otherwise you have to resort to platform-dependent functions like [`pthread_exit`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_exit.html) on POSIX platforms.

Comment: So if I call exit from the child thread is it guaranteed to cleanly terminate the entire process? Because I eventually want to terminate all the processes but read somewhere on SO that calling exit from a child thread is not reliable.

Comment: Calling `exit` will terminate the current *process* and all threads. If it will be "clean" depends on the operating system and what resources you have created/allocated. For example on Linux, all allocated memory will be released, all file descriptors (which includes sockets and pipes) will be closed, and the program be unloaded from memory (unless the process has forked).

Comment: Which platform ? You want the code to be portable ?

Comment: @Jagannath Linux. Not really but I would like to stick with c++11 and not use pthreads or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to use `std::async` and throw an exception from the thread you wish to terminate. Then you could call `get()` on the `future` returned by your async call to retrieve the exception and terminate gracefully. Something like this, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

void A();
void B();
void C();
void D();

void A() { while (true) B(); }
void B() { while (true) C(); }
void C() { while (true) D(); }
void D() { throw -1; }

int main()
{
    auto future = std::async(A);

    try {
        future.get();
    }
    catch (int e) {
        // Handle thread termination
        std::cout << "Thread threw exception " << e << '\n';
    }

    std::cout << "Application terminating..." << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So an exception will be thrown in the main thread that made the async as well? If it is then that might be a problem since my main program moves on to do other work after creating the child thread and I'm hoping to periodically check if the child thread exited. And I don't know if it is good practise to wrap the entire main program in a try block.

Comment: @SidharthMudgal Not necessarily; I just used this as an example. You could catch the exception further down, say in `A()`, and set a flag somewhere (thread safe and not local to the terminating thread) indicating the thread has terminated. That thread will have terminated, but you could then use the main thread to check the earlier mentioned flag whenever you like.